# Angular: when and why do we need to escape with &amp;gt; and assign with &quot;&quot;?

Tags: angularjs

when and why do we need to escape with `&amp;gt;` and assign with `&quot;&quot;`?
Why is image initiated with escaped quotes `$scope.image = &quot;&quot;`?

```
 function CarouselController($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.images = [];
  $scope.image = &quot;&quot;
  $scope.index = 0;

  $scope.setImages = function(images) {
  $scope.images = images;
  $scope.image = images[0];
  $scope.index = 0;
 };

$scope.nextImage = function() {
$scope.index = ($scope.index + 1) % $scope.images.length;
$scope.image = $scope.images[$scope.index];
};

$scope.prevImage = function() {
$scope.index = ($scope.index - 1 &amp;gt;= 0 ? $scope.index - 1 : $scope.images.length    - 1);
$scope.image = $scope.images[$scope.index];
};

var nextImageTimeout = function() {
$scope.nextImage();
$timeout(nextImageTimeout, 5 * 1000);
};

 $timeout(nextImageTimeout, 5 * 1000);
}
```

src:[excellent intro to directives](http://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/)

Comment: I assume that the article is formatted incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen this used as a convention, ever.  Further, I cannot think of why you would use `&quot;&quot;` to initialise a controller property.  The only thought I did have was that somewhere I'd see a reference to `ng-bind-html` (so that the directive controller was feeding HTML to the template).

I suspect you are seeing a formatting issue in the blog entry, itself.  I think the author has accidentally added unformatted HTML to the example code.